# Populate stacklayout from async task table

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting data from api via async task:

```
public async Task<PostModel.Post[]> GetPostsAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = new Uri("link here");
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostModel.Post[]>(jsonString);
            return rootObject;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Also I've created a simple vertical view:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="MainView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">
                        <Frame OutlineColor="Black">
                            <Label x:Name="Title" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Image x:Name="Image" Source="{Binding path}" />
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Wrote a custom cell for displaying data:

```
 public CustomCell()
    {
        //instantiate items in views
        var Image = new Image();
        var NameLabel = new Label();
        var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout() { BackgroundColor = Color.WhiteSmoke };

        //set bindings
        NameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
        Image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("path"));
        Image.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
        Image.HeightRequest = 600;
        Image.WidthRequest = 600;
        NameLabel.FontSize = 24;

        //add views to the view hierarchy
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(NameLabel);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(Image);

        //add to parent view
        View = horizontalLayout;
    }
```

Now I'd like to populate layout from the async task dynamically. For example if task gets 6 items - create 6 cells with data from each of the async task items. Any suggestions how can i do it? I'm completely green in xamarin.forms and just started trying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in OnAppearing, just set the source for your ListView

```
MainView.ItemSource = await GetPostsAsync();
```

Comment: Works, thanks. I tried to do it with foreach, but it was called before a table with posts has been populated.